# How to count the number of characters without spaces?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to this, so please understand me;/

I'm creating an app in appery.io and it has to count the number of letters of text inserted by the app user(without spaces).

I have an input field created(input), a button to press and show the result in a label(result)

the code for the button:

```
var myString = getElementById("input");

var length = myString.length;

Apperyio('result').text(length);
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: getElementById("input").value

Comment: So, can you clarify what it is that you are trying to achieve?  Are you trying to count the number of characters in a string that are NOT spaces?

Answer (score 18):

To ignore a literal space, you can use regex with a space:

```
// get the string
let myString = getElementById("input").value;

// use / /g to remove all spaces from the string
let remText = myString.replace(/ /g, "");

// get the length of the string after removal
let length = remText.length;
```

To ignore all white space(new lines, spaces, tabs) use the \s quantifier:

```
// get the string
let myString = getElementById("input").value;

// use the \s quantifier to remove all white space
let remText = myString.replace(/\s/g, "")

// get the length of the string after removal
let length = remText.length;
```

Answer (score 9):

Use this:

```
var myString = getElementById("input").value;
var withoutSpace = myString.replace(/ /g,"");
var length = withoutSpace.length;
```

Comment: If you need to get rid of spaces, one trick can also to be `var newstring = myString.replace(/ /g,""); var length = newString.length`.  Just a quick way to guarantee no spaces are there.

Answer (score 1):

```
 count = 0;
        const textLenght = 'ABC ABC';
        for (var i = 0, len = textLenght.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (textLenght[i] !== ' ')
                count++;
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.

Answer (score 0):

You can count white spaces and subtract it from lenght of string for example

```
var my_string = "John Doe's iPhone6";
var spaceCount = (my_string.split(" ").length - 1);
console.log(spaceCount);
console.log('total count:- ', my_string.length - spaceCount)
```

Comment: removing all spaces is way easier and takes less lines of code

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to count numbers and ignore everything else (not just spaces):

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var input = document.getElementById("input").value; // get textbox value
  var count = input.match(/\d/g)?.length || 0; // get count, fallback to 0
  window.console.log(count); // print result
});
```

```html
<input id="input" />
<button type="button" id="button">Get Count</button>
```