# How to exclude empty spaces when counting length in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I am checking the length of a title and setting a class, based on that length. I noticed though, that the length is also checking the *empty spaces*, so when you have a **space**, it would count as +1.

I want to get rid of that. So I want to exclude the count of empty spaces in the length. How can I do it, if it's possible?

```
<h1 ng-class="{'specific-class': title.name.length >= 10}">{{title.name}}</h1>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count the number of characters without spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389745/how-to-count-the-number-of-characters-without-spaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check this by replacing the spaces with empty strings:

```
title.name.replace(' ','').length >= 10
```

The full line would be:

```
<h1 ng-class="{'specific-class': title.name.replace(' ','').length >= 10}">{{title.name}}</h1>
```

Say if `title.name` was `'Hello World!'`, `title.name.length` would be 12, but `title.name.replace(' ','').length` is 11.

**EDIT**

Turns out you can't use slashes inside HTML or Angular will convert them to html-safe characters. I'd suggest therefore to separate the checker out into its own module. I've attached a snippet so you can see how it's done:

```
angular
  .module("app", [])
  .controller("test", function($scope) {
    // Example title object. Just load title objects as you would normally.
    $scope.title = {name: 'The World of McNamara'};

    // The actual magic happens here:
    $scope.checker = function(word) {
      return word.replace(/\s/g, '').length >= 10;
    }
  })
```

```css
.specific-class {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<!-- snippet checks whatever is passed to it as title.name -->
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test">
  <h1 ng-class="{'specific-class': checker(title.name)}">{{title.name}}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope, your suggestion doesn't work... I tried the edited one, but it doesn't pass the classname (while mine does), even when the length is 5 or something... Both of your snippets don't work btw. No classname is passed.

Comment: Can you post an example title name?

Comment: For example: "The World of McNamara". This is clearly more than 5, so it should work, yet the classname isn't being passed.

Comment: `'The World of McNamara'.length == 21`. `'The World of McNamara'.replace(/\s/g,'').length == 18`. Both are longer than 5 characters. What are you expecting the outcome to be?

Comment: Well... it doesn't give the classname! So I know it's longer, but it doesn't pass the classname WHILE it's longer. That's the problem...

Comment: Right, in that case it sounds like you just have an Angular or CSS problem. Are you sure Angular is loaded correctly and the CSS class exists and is correctly spelled, etc?

Comment: Thanks Aron, yet it's not what I am looking for... your solution suggests that I need to check EVERY word I am trying to give a class too.. I have a list of dozens of names... I can't do that.

Comment: What do you mean? You just put the function in the controller and add `ng-class="{'specific-class': checker(title.name)}"` every time you want it displayed - just like your example.

Comment: The thing is, you have added the "World of McNamara" into your scope. That's hardcoded, while I want a dynamic check on every name I have... it's not only this one.

Comment: Whichever way you're loading your `title` objects the html will run the checker on every `title.name`. I just put the string inside the controller as an example, but you can load them any way you want. The only requirement is that the function is in scope, that's all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133650/discussion-between-aron-and-siyah).

Comment: No need to, because you fixed it! I will suggest an edit with the right answer that worked for me, so that others can use it too. Thanks mate! Upvoted and accepted the answer!

Comment: Excellent. Once you've done that I'd be grateful if you upvoted and accept my answer as correct :)

Comment: Thanks! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use .trim :

```
title.name.trim().length
```

Or you could do :

```
title.name.replace(" ", "").length
```

EDIT :

In your code it would be like so :

```
<h1 ng-class="{'specific-class': title.name.replace(' ', '').length >= 10}">{{title.name}}</h1>
```

Using ternary logic :

```
<h1 ng-class="(title.name.replace(' ', '').length >= 10)? 'specific-class' : 'another-class' ">{{title.name}}</h1>
```

Comment: `.trim()` only strips out whitespace at either end of a string, not from inside the string.

Comment: Can you give the example, implemented with my snippet?

Comment: Nope, also not working. For example, I have the title: "World of Root" and I have made the length >= 12. This would mean that the class SHOULDN't be given, but it IS given... so it doesn't work. World of Root has 11 letters... so it seems like the spaces aren't excluded at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could do in multiple ways to remove empty spaces from the string like using split and then join.

```
title.name.split(' ').join('')
```

Or could be done by regex approach:

```
title.name.replace(/ /g, '')
```

It is up to you how you want to implement.

Comment: Can you give the full one, using my snippet?

Comment: @Siyah, you just have to put .length at the end. Like: `<h1 ng-class="{'specific-class': title.name.replace(/ /g, '').length >= 10}">{{title.name}}</h1>` or `<h1 ng-class="{'specific-class': title.name.split(' ').join('').length >= 10}">{{title.name}}</h1>`

Comment: Doesn't work. I get this: Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '/' not a primary expression at column 41 of the expression