# How to Prevent Spaces to Be Counted as Characters?

Tags: javascript

I've got a search box and works quite good actually. What it does is that you type something and if it already exists, it shows you the topic. If not, it sends you to page that you can open this topic. When you type "ABC" or "A BC", it's okay but when you try to type "AB" and then try to search, it gives you an error that you need to type at least 3 characters, which is good. But it can be easily done like ("a space space" - counts 3). You may open topics with spaces, sure, but don't want that spaces to be counted. Such as, (hello world) It should be counted as 10 characters, not 11. How to exclude spaces to be counted as characters? It's a project I'm working on to make it better, I have not written all by myself.

Here are my search box's all javascript files which I probably need to edit but don't know how:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function formatText(tag) {
   var Field = document.getElementById('entry_girdi');
   var val = Field.value;
   var selected_txt = val.substring(Field.selectionStart, Field.selectionEnd);
   var before_txt = val.substring(0, Field.selectionStart);
   var after_txt = val.substring(Field.selectionEnd, val.length);
 Field.value += '[' + tag + '/]';
}
</script>
```

```js
!function(a){var b="0.9.3",c={isMsie:function(){var a=/(msie) ([\w.]+)/i.exec(navigator.userAgent);return a?parseInt(a[2],10):!1},isBlankString:function(a){return!a||/^\s*$/.test(a)},escapeRegExChars:function(a){return a.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g,"\\$&")},isString:function(a){return"string"==typeof a},isNumber:function(a){return"number"==typeof a},isArray:a.isArray,isFunction:a.isFunction,isObject:a.isPlainObject,isUndefined:function(a){return"undefined"==typeof a},bind:a.proxy,bindAll:function(b){var c;for(var d in b)a.isFunction(c=b[d])&&(b[d]=a.proxy(c,b))},indexOf:function(a,b){for(var c=0;c<a.length;c++)if(a[c]===b)return c;return-1},each:a.each,map:a.map,filter:a.grep,every:function(b,c){var d=!0;return b?(a.each(b,function(a,e){return(d=c.call(null,e,a,b))?void 0:!1}),!!d):d},some:function(b,c){var d=!1;return b?(a.each(b,function(a,e){return(d=c.call(null,e,a,b))?!1:void 0}),!!d):d},mixin:a.extend,getUniqueId:function(){var a=0;return function(){return a++}}(),defer:function(a){setTimeout(a,0)},debounce:function(a,b,c){var d,e;return function(){var f,g,h=this,i=arguments;return f=function(){d=null,c||(e=a.apply(h,i))},g=c&&!d,clearTimeout(d),d=setTimeout(f,b),g&&(e=a.apply(h,i)),e}},throttle:function(a,b){var c,d,e,f,g,h;return g=0,h=function(){g=new Date,e=null,f=a.apply(c,d)},function(){var i=new Date,j=b-(i-g);return c=this,d=arguments,0>=j?(clearTimeout(e),e=null,g=i,f=a.apply(c,d)):e||(e=setTimeout(h,j)),f}},tokenizeQuery:function(b){return a.trim(b).toLowerCase().split(/[\s]+/)},tokenizeText:function(b){return a.trim(b).toLowerCase().split(/[\s\-_]+/)},getProtocol:function(){return location.protocol},noop:function(){}},d=function(){var a=/\s+/;return{on:function(b,c){var d;if(!c)return this;for(this._callbacks=this._callbacks||{},b=b.split(a);d=b.shift();)this._callbacks[d]=this._callbacks[d]||[],this._callbacks[d].push(c);return this},trigger:function(b,c){var d,e;if(!this._callbacks)return this;for(b=b.split(a);d=b.shift();)if(e=this._callbacks[d])for(var f=0;f<e.length;f+=1)e[f].call(this,{type:d,data:c});return this}}}(),e=function(){function b(b){b&&b.el||a.error("EventBus initialized without el"),this.$el=a(b.el)}var d="typeahead:";return c.mixin(b.prototype,{trigger:function(a){var b=[].slice.call(arguments,1);this.$el.trigger(d+a,b)}}),b}(),f=function(){function a(a){this.prefix=["__",a,"__"].join(""),this.ttlKey="__ttl__",this.keyMatcher=new RegExp("^"+this.prefix)}function b(){return(new Date).getTime()}function d(a){return JSON.stringify(c.isUndefined(a)?null:a)}function e(a){return JSON.parse(a)}var f,g;try{f=window.localStorage,f.setItem("~~~","!"),f.removeItem("~~~")}catch(h){f=null}return g=f&&window.JSON?{_prefix:function(a){return this.prefix+a},_ttlKey:function(a){return this._prefix(a)+this.ttlKey},get:function(a){return this.isExpired(a)&&this.remove(a),e(f.getItem(this._prefix(a)))},set:function(a,e,g){return c.isNumber(g)?f.setItem(this._ttlKey(a),d(b()+g)):f.removeItem(this._ttlKey(a)),f.setItem(this._prefix(a),d(e))},remove:function(a){return f.removeItem(this._ttlKey(a)),f.removeItem(this._prefix(a)),this},clear:function(){var a,b,c=[],d=f.length;for(a=0;d>a;a++)(b=f.key(a)).match(this.keyMatcher)&&c.push(b.replace(this.keyMatcher,""));for(a=c.length;a--;)this.remove(c[a]);return this},isExpired:function(a){var d=e(f.getItem(this._ttlKey(a)));return c.isNumber(d)&&b()>d?!0:!1}}:{get:c.noop,set:c.noop,remove:c.noop,clear:c.noop,isExpired:c.noop},c.mixin(a.prototype,g),a}(),g=function(){function a(a){c.bindAll(this),a=a||{},this.sizeLimit=a.sizeLimit||10,this.cache={},this.cachedKeysByAge=[]}return c.mixin(a.prototype,{get:function(a){return this.cache[a]},set:function(a,b){var c;this.cachedKeysByAge.length===this.sizeLimit&&(c=this.cachedKeysByAge.shift(),delete this.cache[c]),this.cache[a]=b,this.cachedKeysByAge.push(a)}}),a}(),h=function(){function b(a){c.bindAll(this),a=c.isString(a)?{url:a}:a,i=i||new g,h=c.isNumber(a.maxParallelRequests)?a.maxParallelRequests:h||6,this.url=a.url,this.wildcard=a.wildcard||"%QUERY",this.filter=a.filter,this.replace=a.replace,this.ajaxSettings={type:"get",cache:a.cache,timeout:a.timeout,dataType:a.dataType||"json",beforeSend:a.beforeSend},this._get=(/^throttle$/i.test(a.rateLimitFn)?c.throttle:c.debounce)(this._get,a.rateLimitWait||300)}function d(){j++}function e(){j--}function f(){return h>j}var h,i,j=0,k={};return c.mixin(b.prototype,{_get:function(a,b){function c(c){var e=d.filter?d.filter(c):c;b&&b(e),i.set(a,c)}var d=this;f()?this._sendRequest(a).done(c):this.onDeckRequestArgs=[].slice.call(arguments,0)},_sendRequest:function(b){function c(){e(),k[b]=null,f.onDeckRequestArgs&&(f._get.apply(f,f.onDeckRequestArgs),f.onDeckRequestArgs=null)}var f=this,g=k[b];return g||(d(),g=k[b]=a.ajax(b,this.ajaxSettings).always(c)),g},get:function(a,b){var d,e,f=this,g=encodeURIComponent(a||"");return b=b||c.noop,d=this.replace?this.replace(this.url,g):this.url.replace(this.wildcard,g),(e=i.get(d))?c.defer(function(){b(f.filter?f.filter(e):e)}):this._get(d,b),!!e}}),b}(),i=function(){function d(b){c.bindAll(this),c.isString(b.template)&&!b.engine&&a.error("no template engine specified"),b.local||b.prefetch||b.remote||a.error("one of local, prefetch, or remote is required"),this.name=b.name||c.getUniqueId(),this.limit=b.limit||5,this.minLength=b.minLength||1,this.header=b.header,this.footer=b.footer,this.valueKey=b.valueKey||"value",this.template=e(b.template,b.engine,this.valueKey),this.local=b.local,this.prefetch=b.prefetch,this.remote=b.remote,this.itemHash={},this.adjacencyList={},this.storage=b.name?new f(b.name):null}function e(a,b,d){var e,f;return c.isFunction(a)?e=a:c.isString(a)?(f=b.compile(a),e=c.bind(f.render,f)):e=function(a){return"<p>"+a[d]+"</p>"},e}var g={thumbprint:"thumbprint",protocol:"protocol",itemHash:"itemHash",adjacencyList:"adjacencyList"};return c.mixin(d.prototype,{_processLocalData:function(a){this._mergeProcessedData(this._processData(a))},_loadPrefetchData:function(d){function e(a){var b=d.filter?d.filter(a):a,e=m._processData(b),f=e.itemHash,h=e.adjacencyList;m.storage&&(m.storage.set(g.itemHash,f,d.ttl),m.storage.set(g.adjacencyList,h,d.ttl),m.storage.set(g.thumbprint,n,d.ttl),m.storage.set(g.protocol,c.getProtocol(),d.ttl)),m._mergeProcessedData(e)}var f,h,i,j,k,l,m=this,n=b+(d.thumbprint||"");return this.storage&&(f=this.storage.get(g.thumbprint),h=this.storage.get(g.protocol),i=this.storage.get(g.itemHash),j=this.storage.get(g.adjacencyList)),k=f!==n||h!==c.getProtocol(),d=c.isString(d)?{url:d}:d,d.ttl=c.isNumber(d.ttl)?d.ttl:864e5,i&&j&&!k?(this._mergeProcessedData({itemHash:i,adjacencyList:j}),l=a.Deferred().resolve()):l=a.getJSON(d.url).done(e),l},_transformDatum:function(a){var b=c.isString(a)?a:a[this.valueKey],d=a.tokens||c.tokenizeText(b),e={value:b,tokens:d};return c.isString(a)?(e.datum={},e.datum[this.valueKey]=a):e.datum=a,e.tokens=c.filter(e.tokens,function(a){return!c.isBlankString(a)}),e.tokens=c.map(e.tokens,function(a){return a.toLowerCase()}),e},_processData:function(a){var b=this,d={},e={};return c.each(a,function(a,f){var g=b._transformDatum(f),h=c.getUniqueId(g.value);d[h]=g,c.each(g.tokens,function(a,b){var d=b.charAt(0),f=e[d]||(e[d]=[h]);!~c.indexOf(f,h)&&f.push(h)})}),{itemHash:d,adjacencyList:e}},_mergeProcessedData:function(a){var b=this;c.mixin(this.itemHash,a.itemHash),c.each(a.adjacencyList,function(a,c){var d=b.adjacencyList[a];b.adjacencyList[a]=d?d.concat(c):c})},_getLocalSuggestions:function(a){var b,d=this,e=[],f=[],g=[];return c.each(a,function(a,b){var d=b.charAt(0);!~c.indexOf(e,d)&&e.push(d)}),c.each(e,function(a,c){var e=d.adjacencyList[c];return e?(f.push(e),(!b||e.length<b.length)&&(b=e),void 0):!1}),f.length<e.length?[]:(c.each(b,function(b,e){var h,i,j=d.itemHash[e];h=c.every(f,function(a){return~c.indexOf(a,e)}),i=h&&c.every(a,function(a){return c.some(j.tokens,function(b){return 0===b.indexOf(a)})}),i&&g.push(j)}),g)},initialize:function(){var b;return this.local&&this._processLocalData(this.local),this.transport=this.remote?new h(this.remote):null,b=this.prefetch?this._loadPrefetchData(this.prefetch):a.Deferred().resolve(),this.local=this.prefetch=this.remote=null,this.initialize=function(){return b},b},getSuggestions:function(a,b){function d(a){f=f.slice(0),c.each(a,function(a,b){var d,e=g._transformDatum(b);return d=c.some(f,function(a){return e.value===a.value}),!d&&f.push(e),f.length<g.limit}),b&&b(f)}var e,f,g=this,h=!1;a.length<this.minLength||(e=c.tokenizeQuery(a),f=this._getLocalSuggestions(e).slice(0,this.limit),f.length<this.limit&&this.transport&&(h=this.transport.get(a,d)),!h&&b&&b(f))}}),d}(),j=function(){function b(b){var d=this;c.bindAll(this),this.specialKeyCodeMap={9:"tab",27:"esc",37:"left",39:"right",13:"enter",38:"up",40:"down"},this.$hint=a(b.hint),this.$input=a(b.input).on("blur.tt",this._handleBlur).on("focus.tt",this._handleFocus).on("keydown.tt",this._handleSpecialKeyEvent),c.isMsie()?this.$input.on("keydown.tt keypress.tt cut.tt paste.tt",function(a){d.specialKeyCodeMap[a.which||a.keyCode]||c.defer(d._compareQueryToInputValue)}):this.$input.on("input.tt",this._compareQueryToInputValue),this.query=this.$input.val(),this.$overflowHelper=e(this.$input)}function e(b){return a("<span></span>").css({position:"absolute",left:"-9999px",visibility:"hidden",whiteSpace:"nowrap",fontFamily:b.css("font-family"),fontSize:b.css("font-size"),fontStyle:b.css("font-style"),fontVariant:b.css("font-variant"),fontWeight:b.css("font-weight"),wordSpacing:b.css("word-spacing"),letterSpacing:b.css("letter-spacing"),textIndent:b.css("text-indent"),textRendering:b.css("text-rendering"),textTransform:b.css("text-transform")}).insertAfter(b)}function f(a,b){return a=(a||"").replace(/^\s*/g,"").replace(/\s{2,}/g," "),b=(b||"").replace(/^\s*/g,"").replace(/\s{2,}/g," "),a===b}return c.mixin(b.prototype,d,{_handleFocus:function(){this.trigger("focused")},_handleBlur:function(){this.trigger("blured")},_handleSpecialKeyEvent:function(a){var b=this.specialKeyCodeMap[a.which||a.keyCode];b&&this.trigger(b+"Keyed",a)},_compareQueryToInputValue:function(){var a=this.getInputValue(),b=f(this.query,a),c=b?this.query.length!==a.length:!1;c?this.trigger("whitespaceChanged",{value:this.query}):b||this.trigger("queryChanged",{value:this.query=a})},destroy:function(){this.$hint.off(".tt"),this.$input.off(".tt"),this.$hint=this.$input=this.$overflowHelper=null},focus:function(){this.$input.focus()},blur:function(){this.$input.blur()},getQuery:function(){return this.query},setQuery:function(a){this.query=a},getInputValue:function(){return this.$input.val()},setInputValue:function(a,b){this.$input.val(a),!b&&this._compareQueryToInputValue()},getHintValue:function(){return this.$hint.val()},setHintValue:function(a){this.$hint.val(a)},getLanguageDirection:function(){return(this.$input.css("direction")||"ltr").toLowerCase()},isOverflow:function(){return this.$overflowHelper.text(this.getInputValue()),this.$overflowHelper.width()>this.$input.width()},isCursorAtEnd:function(){var a,b=this.$input.val().length,d=this.$input[0].selectionStart;return c.isNumber(d)?d===b:document.selection?(a=document.selection.createRange(),a.moveStart("character",-b),b===a.text.length):!0}}),b}(),k=function(){function b(b){c.bindAll(this),this.isOpen=!1,this.isEmpty=!0,this.isMouseOverDropdown=!1,this.$menu=a(b.menu).on("mouseenter.tt",this._handleMouseenter).on("mouseleave.tt",this._handleMouseleave).on("click.tt",".tt-suggestion",this._handleSelection).on("mouseover.tt",".tt-suggestion",this._handleMouseover)}function e(a){return a.data("suggestion")}var f={suggestionsList:'<span class="tt-suggestions"></span>'},g={suggestionsList:{display:"block"},suggestion:{whiteSpace:"nowrap",cursor:"pointer"},suggestionChild:{whiteSpace:"normal"}};return c.mixin(b.prototype,d,{_handleMouseenter:function(){this.isMouseOverDropdown=!0},_handleMouseleave:function(){this.isMouseOverDropdown=!1},_handleMouseover:function(b){var c=a(b.currentTarget);this._getSuggestions().removeClass("tt-is-under-cursor"),c.addClass("tt-is-under-cursor")},_handleSelection:function(b){var c=a(b.currentTarget);this.trigger("suggestionSelected",e(c))},_show:function(){this.$menu.css("display","block")},_hide:function(){this.$menu.hide()},_moveCursor:function(a){var b,c,d,f;if(this.isVisible()){if(b=this._getSuggestions(),c=b.filter(".tt-is-under-cursor"),c.removeClass("tt-is-under-cursor"),d=b.index(c)+a,d=(d+1)%(b.length+1)-1,-1===d)return this.trigger("cursorRemoved"),void 0;-1>d&&(d=b.length-1),f=b.eq(d).addClass("tt-is-under-cursor"),this._ensureVisibility(f),this.trigger("cursorMoved",e(f))}},_getSuggestions:function(){return this.$menu.find(".tt-suggestions > .tt-suggestion")},_ensureVisibility:function(a){var b=this.$menu.height()+parseInt(this.$menu.css("paddingTop"),10)+parseInt(this.$menu.css("paddingBottom"),10),c=this.$menu.scrollTop(),d=a.position().top,e=d+a.outerHeight(!0);0>d?this.$menu.scrollTop(c+d):e>b&&this.$menu.scrollTop(c+(e-b))},destroy:function(){this.$menu.off(".tt"),this.$menu=null},isVisible:function(){return this.isOpen&&!this.isEmpty},closeUnlessMouseIsOverDropdown:function(){this.isMouseOverDropdown||this.close()},close:function(){this.isOpen&&(this.isOpen=!1,this.isMouseOverDropdown=!1,this._hide(),this.$menu.find(".tt-suggestions > .tt-suggestion").removeClass("tt-is-under-cursor"),this.trigger("closed"))},open:function(){this.isOpen||(this.isOpen=!0,!this.isEmpty&&this._show(),this.trigger("opened"))},setLanguageDirection:function(a){var b={left:"0",right:"auto"},c={left:"auto",right:" 0"};"ltr"===a?this.$menu.css(b):this.$menu.css(c)},moveCursorUp:function(){this._moveCursor(-1)},moveCursorDown:function(){this._moveCursor(1)},getSuggestionUnderCursor:function(){var a=this._getSuggestions().filter(".tt-is-under-cursor").first();return a.length>0?e(a):null},getFirstSuggestion:function(){var a=this._getSuggestions().first();return a.length>0?e(a):null},renderSuggestions:function(b,d){var e,h,i,j,k,l="tt-dataset-"+b.name,m='<div class="tt-suggestion">%body</div>',n=this.$menu.find("."+l);0===n.length&&(h=a(f.suggestionsList).css(g.suggestionsList),n=a("<div></div>").addClass(l).append(b.header).append(h).append(b.footer).appendTo(this.$menu)),d.length>0?(this.isEmpty=!1,this.isOpen&&this._show(),i=document.createElement("div"),j=document.createDocumentFragment(),c.each(d,function(c,d){d.dataset=b.name,e=b.template(d.datum),i.innerHTML=m.replace("%body",e),k=a(i.firstChild).css(g.suggestion).data("suggestion",d),k.children().each(function(){a(this).css(g.suggestionChild)}),j.appendChild(k[0])}),n.show().find(".tt-suggestions").html(j)):this.clearSuggestions(b.name),this.trigger("suggestionsRendered")},clearSuggestions:function(a){var b=a?this.$menu.find(".tt-dataset-"+a):this.$menu.find('[class^="tt-dataset-"]'),c=b.find(".tt-suggestions");b.hide(),c.empty(),0===this._getSuggestions().length&&(this.isEmpty=!0,this._hide())}}),b}(),l=function(){function b(a){var b,d,f;c.bindAll(this),this.$node=e(a.input),this.datasets=a.datasets,this.dir=null,this.eventBus=a.eventBus,b=this.$node.find(".tt-dropdown-menu"),d=this.$node.find(".tt-query"),f=this.$node.find(".tt-hint"),this.dropdownView=new k({menu:b}).on("suggestionSelected",this._handleSelection).on("cursorMoved",this._clearHint).on("cursorMoved",this._setInputValueToSuggestionUnderCursor).on("cursorRemoved",this._setInputValueToQuery).on("cursorRemoved",this._updateHint).on("suggestionsRendered",this._updateHint).on("opened",this._updateHint).on("closed",this._clearHint).on("opened closed",this._propagateEvent),this.inputView=new j({input:d,hint:f}).on("focused",this._openDropdown).on("blured",this._closeDropdown).on("blured",this._setInputValueToQuery).on("enterKeyed tabKeyed",this._handleSelection).on("queryChanged",this._clearHint).on("queryChanged",this._clearSuggestions).on("queryChanged",this._getSuggestions).on("whitespaceChanged",this._updateHint).on("queryChanged whitespaceChanged",this._openDropdown).on("queryChanged whitespaceChanged",this._setLanguageDirection).on("escKeyed",this._closeDropdown).on("escKeyed",this._setInputValueToQuery).on("tabKeyed upKeyed downKeyed",this._managePreventDefault).on("upKeyed downKeyed",this._moveDropdownCursor).on("upKeyed downKeyed",this._openDropdown).on("tabKeyed leftKeyed rightKeyed",this._autocomplete)}function e(b){var c=a(g.wrapper),d=a(g.dropdown),e=a(b),f=a(g.hint);c=c.css(h.wrapper),d=d.css(h.dropdown),f.css(h.hint).css({backgroundAttachment:e.css("background-attachment"),backgroundClip:e.css("background-clip"),backgroundColor:e.css("background-color"),backgroundImage:e.css("background-image"),backgroundOrigin:e.css("background-origin"),backgroundPosition:e.css("background-position"),backgroundRepeat:e.css("background-repeat"),backgroundSize:e.css("background-size")}),e.data("ttAttrs",{dir:e.attr("dir"),autocomplete:e.attr("autocomplete"),spellcheck:e.attr("spellcheck"),style:e.attr("style")}),e.addClass("tt-query").attr({autocomplete:"off",spellcheck:!1}).css(h.query);try{!e.attr("dir")&&e.attr("dir","auto")}catch(i){}return e.wrap(c).parent().prepend(f).append(d)}function f(a){var b=a.find(".tt-query");c.each(b.data("ttAttrs"),function(a,d){c.isUndefined(d)?b.removeAttr(a):b.attr(a,d)}),b.detach().removeData("ttAttrs").removeClass("tt-query").insertAfter(a),a.remove()}var g={wrapper:'<span class="twitter-typeahead"></span>',hint:'<input class="tt-hint" type="text" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="off" disabled>',dropdown:'<span class="tt-dropdown-menu"></span>'},h={wrapper:{position:"relative",display:"inline-block"},hint:{position:"absolute",top:"0",left:"0",borderColor:"transparent",boxShadow:"none"},query:{position:"relative",verticalAlign:"to1p",backgroundColor:"transparent"},dropdown:{position:"absolute",top:"100%",left:"0",zIndex:"100",display:"none"}};return c.isMsie()&&c.mixin(h.query,{backgroundImage:"url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7)"}),c.isMsie()&&c.isMsie()<=7&&(c.mixin(h.wrapper,{display:"inline",zoom:"1"}),c.mixin(h.query,{marginTop:"-1px"})),c.mixin(b.prototype,d,{_managePreventDefault:function(a){var b,c,d=a.data,e=!1;switch(a.type){case"tabKeyed":b=this.inputView.getHintValue(),c=this.inputView.getInputValue(),e=b&&b!==c;break;case"upKeyed":case"downKeyed":e=!d.shiftKey&&!d.ctrlKey&&!d.metaKey}e&&d.preventDefault()},_setLanguageDirection:function(){var a=this.inputView.getLanguageDirection();a!==this.dir&&(this.dir=a,this.$node.css("direction",a),this.dropdownView.setLanguageDirection(a))},_updateHint:function(){var a,b,d,e,f,g=this.dropdownView.getFirstSuggestion(),h=g?g.value:null,i=this.dropdownView.isVisible(),j=this.inputView.isOverflow();h&&i&&!j&&(a=this.inputView.getInputValue(),b=a.replace(/\s{2,}/g," ").replace(/^\s+/g,""),d=c.escapeRegExChars(b),e=new RegExp("^(?:"+d+")(.*$)","i"),f=e.exec(h),this.inputView.setHintValue(a+(f?f[1]:"")))},_clearHint:function(){this.inputView.setHintValue("")},_clearSuggestions:function(){this.dropdownView.clearSuggestions()},_setInputValueToQuery:function(){this.inputView.setInputValue(this.inputView.getQuery())},_setInputValueToSuggestionUnderCursor:function(a){var b=a.data;this.inputView.setInputValue(b.value,!0)},_openDropdown:function(){this.dropdownView.open()},_closeDropdown:function(a){this.dropdownView["blured"===a.type?"closeUnlessMouseIsOverDropdown":"close"]()},_moveDropdownCursor:function(a){var b=a.data;b.shiftKey||b.ctrlKey||b.metaKey||this.dropdownView["upKeyed"===a.type?"moveCursorUp":"moveCursorDown"]()},_handleSelection:function(a){var b="suggestionSelected"===a.type,d=b?a.data:this.dropdownView.getSuggestionUnderCursor();d&&(this.inputView.setInputValue(d.value),b?this.inputView.focus():a.data.preventDefault(),b&&c.isMsie()?c.defer(this.dropdownView.close):this.dropdownView.close(),this.eventBus.trigger("selected",d.datum,d.dataset))},_getSuggestions:function(){var a=this,b=this.inputView.getQuery();c.isBlankString(b)||c.each(this.datasets,function(c,d){d.getSuggestions(b,function(c){b===a.inputView.getQuery()&&a.dropdownView.renderSuggestions(d,c)})})},_autocomplete:function(a){var b,c,d,e,f;("rightKeyed"!==a.type&&"leftKeyed"!==a.type||(b=this.inputView.isCursorAtEnd(),c="ltr"===this.inputView.getLanguageDirection()?"leftKeyed"===a.type:"rightKeyed"===a.type,b&&!c))&&(d=this.inputView.getQuery(),e=this.inputView.getHintValue(),""!==e&&d!==e&&(f=this.dropdownView.getFirstSuggestion(),this.inputView.setInputValue(f.value),this.eventBus.trigger("autocompleted",f.datum,f.dataset)))},_propagateEvent:function(a){this.eventBus.trigger(a.type)},destroy:function(){this.inputView.destroy(),this.dropdownView.destroy(),f(this.$node),this.$node=null},setQuery:function(a){this.inputView.setQuery(a),this.inputView.setInputValue(a),this._clearHint(),this._clearSuggestions(),this._getSuggestions()}}),b}();!function(){var b,d={},f="ttView";b={initialize:function(b){function g(){var b,d=a(this),g=new e({el:d});b=c.map(h,function(a){return a.initialize()}),d.data(f,new l({input:d,eventBus:g=new e({el:d}),datasets:h})),a.when.apply(a,b).always(function(){c.defer(function(){g.trigger("initialized")})})}var h;return b=c.isArray(b)?b:[b],0===b.length&&a.error("no datasets provided"),h=c.map(b,function(a){var b=d[a.name]?d[a.name]:new i(a);return a.name&&(d[a.name]=b),b}),this.each(g)},destroy:function(){function b(){var b=a(this),c=b.data(f);c&&(c.destroy(),b.removeData(f))}return this.each(b)},setQuery:function(b){function c(){var c=a(this).data(f);c&&c.setQuery(b)}return this.each(c)}},jQuery.fn.typeahead=function(a){return b[a]?b[a].apply(this,[].slice.call(arguments,1)):b.initialize.apply(this,arguments)}}()}(window.jQuery);
```

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/typeahead.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        name: 'typeahead',
        remote:'/search.php?key=%QUERY',
        limit : 10
    });
});
    </script>
 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    
    //Disable part of page
    $('input#ara').bind('cut copy paste', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function numbersonly(myfield, e, dec) {
            var key;
            var keychar;
 
            if (window.event)
                key = window.event.keyCode;
            else if (e)
                key = e.which;
            else
                return true;
            keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);
 
            // control keys
            if ((key == null) || (key == 0) || (key == 8) ||
    (key == 9) || (key == 13) || (key == 27))
                return true;
 
            // numbers
            else if ((("ABCÇDEFGĞHIİJKLMNOÖPQRSŞTUÜVWXYZabcçdefgğhıijklmnoöpqrsştuüvwxyz0123456789").indexOf(keychar) > -1))
                return true;
 
            // decimal point jump
            else if (dec && (keychar == ".")) {
                myfield.form.elements[dec].focus();
                return false;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
</script>
```

My another topic has been marked as duplicate but to be honest, I don't really know how to adapt these suggested lines to my js codes to get it working properly.

```js
var myString = getElementById("input").value;
var withoutSpace = myString.replace(/ /g,"");
var length = withoutSpace.length;
```

Comment: What do you not understand about the suggested answer?

Comment: Where does the code you've written check whether or not the minimum length is met? That's where you need to put the suggested lines. The suggested lines removes spaces (you should also check for tabs and returns too) then gets the number of characters in the string.

Comment: As I understand, what you need is [`trim`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) that would remove spaces from the user input search string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count the number of characters without spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389745/how-to-count-the-number-of-characters-without-spaces)

Comment: It's not duplicate. As I said, I want people to use spaces, it's alright. But I don't want spaces to be counted as characters.

Comment: You can count the total characters, and then count the spaces (split by spaces then array length). A simple substraction then do the work of how many actual characters you have.

Comment: @AleOtero93 would you please tell me how to do it? My javascript skills are pretty bad at the moment, sorry.

Comment: @mawendir posted in answer

Answer (score 0):

You just take the value, in your case `val`, and strip out the spaces.

Change this line:

```
var val = Field.value;
```

To:

```
var val = Field.value.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

I have changed the regex from the solution you've posted with `\s`, which matches all kinds of space, not just the whitespace character.

Comment: Didn't work, sadly. I'm willing to share all of my files and give admin access to my site to get it fixed.

Comment: Are you sure your other logic is correct? You have asked how to change your code to ignore spaces, this should do the trick.

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe I misrepresent what I mean. Search box works like this. I type something and it counts the words, if it's below 3 characters, it doesn't let you open a topic. If it's over, then it's fine. But it can be tricked with using spaces, because it counts spaces as words and it thinks when I type "ab(space)", it is 3 words. I want to prevent this to happen, not to remove spaces or prevent people from using spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You could count all the caracters, including spaces, with this:

```
var val = Field.value;
var chars = val.length;
```

Then you can count how many spaces do you have:

```
var spacesArr = val.split(" ");
var spaces = spacesArr.length;
```

Finally, if you substract the values, you have the actual characters count:

```
var actualLength = chars - spaces;
```