# javascript substr chars without counting spaces

Tags: javascript, substr

I have a text description with css of

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

and it includes spaces and new lines etc...

I would like to limit number of characters in description without counting spaces:

```
description = description.substr(0,100);
```

Of course I need to preserve description formatting.

How could I do that?

Comment: What do you mean with `I need to preserve description formatting` and why is that a problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count the number of characters without spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389745/how-to-count-the-number-of-characters-without-spaces)

Comment: Please check my answer. it returns exactly you want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this function. This returns exactly desired value:

```
function mySubstr(a/*description*/, c/*count*/){
    var l=0, dif=0, p=c, 
          dt=[a.substr(0, c)];
    while((l=dt.join("").replace(/\s/g, "").length)<c){
         dt.push(a.substr(p, dif=c-l));
         p+=dif;
    }
    return dt.join("");
}
console.log(mySubstr("1    2 $- 8 58 9&8 85 0j g fg hc 6 4 34 8", 16));
```

[check result online!](http://jsfiddle.net/x6dLqw82/2/)

---

**Added part (method2 - updated version)**:

You can try this. This version supports multi `\s` too:

```
function Substr2(desc, c/*count*/){
    var r="", s=0, m=0, res, ok;
    desc.replace(/(.+?)(\s+)/g, function(a,b,d){
        if(ok) return;  
        m+=b.length;
        r+=a;
        res=r.substr(0, m+s-(m-c));
        if(m>=c) ok=1;
        s+=d.length;
    });
    return res;
};

console.log(Substr2("1 2 $- 8 58 9&8 85 0j g fg hc 6 4 34 8", 16));
```

Comment: Please check my new function in added part (updated ver). This version supports multi \s too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate through all characters of the string, and count all characters that are not spaces (or what ever pattern you want), and as soon as you reach the limit you know where you have to truncate the string:

```js
var description = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14'

function limitLength(str, length, exclude) {
  var i = 0
  for (var count = 0 ; i < str.length && count < length; i++) {
    if (!str[i].match(exclude)) {
      count++
    }
  }
  
  return str.substr(0, i)
}

description = limitLength(description, 15, /([\s])/)

console.log(description)
```

Comment: But this logic is not correct because takes all spaces of the text. for example check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3x2fpq6/2/)

Comment: @HassanSadeghi you are absolutely right, updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

another way without regular expression is that you can count the number after remove whitespace

`description.replace(' ', '').substr(0, 100)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solve your problem:

```
let description = "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Consectetur Adipisicing Elit Sed Do Eiusmod Tempor Incididunt Ut Labore Et Dolore Magna Ali";
let spaceCount = ((description || '').match(/\s+/g) || []).length;
let description1 = description.substr(0, 100 + spaceCount);
// OR
let description2 = description.substr(0, 100 - spaceCount);
console.log(description1, description2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use countable.js library to do this  and its live  by the way counts as per key bored clicks.

All you need is to add it on your html page as javascript link

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/countable/3.0.1/Countable.js"></script>
```

Here is a link to download countable.js

https://github.com/RadLikeWhoa/Countable

and here is example of what it can do

https://sacha.me/Countable/

and here is a link for implemented example:

https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Simple-Live-Character-Counter-with-Javascript-Countable.html

It's so simple to use, you just need to add count beside the element you want to count it, check the options to avoid spaces, dots, commas, and so on.

Hope my post helps you

Good luck